# How can i deploy django app without change paths and other configurations?

Tags: django, virtualenv

Currently i have a project with virtualenv and zc.buildout, but the problem is when i want to deploy this app in a production server.
I want to be capable to deploy an app in production server without change paths (relative to server) and without replace any packages etc.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

With the following structure:

```
repo/
    project/
        settings.py
    local/
```

And these settings:

```
#settings.py
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_LOCAL = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT), 'local')
```

You can install anything in the local folder which is deployment specific, like your buildout and virtualenv and reach it through `PROJECT_LOCAL`. Of course you should ignore `local/*` in your versioning.